# Display Text in Label like Notes

Tags: vb.net, user-interface

In my Application i need to display some short notes in label.

So i tried like this

```
lable1.Text="HELP : " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "1. You can Remove or
Replace existing Main Icons" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
& "2. If you want to remove any buttons, Right click on Icon and 
select UNPIN or select the " _
& " Icon and press delete button from key borad" & vbNewLine & 
vbNewLine & "3. Drag the needed button from top menu and drop it on 
empty space in Icons." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "4. If Reports 
having sub reports, You can drag and drop the sub reports only."
```

If the points in came to second line its start from 2 but i need all letter start same level like this

`1 . aaaa
 2.  bbbbb
     vvvvv`.

and `Help` must have underline. How to do it. Can say which control good for this can you give some example also.
am using `VB.Net 2008`

Comment: Use richtextbox control instead

Comment: and are you looking for something like this - http://hastebin.com/ecasexirah.vbs

Comment: @wingedpanther thanks sir. rich text box works for me but how to add numeric for bullet letters

Comment: what you mean by _numeric for bullet letters_ ?

Comment: Use GDI+ to draw your text onto a form or control.  That way you can put it wherever you want.  The alternative would be to use a fixed-with font and then use text formatted to specific widths.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can set tabs in a label, so you might need to manually space the text using a monospaced font. But in a richtextbox, you can do this.

```
   RichTextBox1.Text = "HELP : " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine &
"1." & vbTab & "You can Remove or Replace existing Main Icons" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine &
"2." & vbTab & "If you want to remove any buttons, Right click on Icon and" & vbNewLine _
 & vbTab & "select UNPIN or select the Icon and press delete button from keyboard" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine &
 "3." & vbTab & "Drag the needed button from top menu and drop it on" & vbNewLine _
 & vbTab & "empty space in Icons." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine &
 "4." & vbTab & "If Reports having sub reports, You can drag and drop the sub reports only."
    RichTextBox1.SelectAll()
    RichTextBox1.SelectionTabs = {20}
    RichTextBox1.DeselectAll
```